# Search on nested Array Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

So I build my API and I have some data, and the front end make this data searchable. I get my data from database using **laravel eloquent**, and make HasMany Relation and get JSON result like this. The data is well.

*JSON*

```
{
    "ID": 444,
    "MODULE_ID": 1112,
    "MODULENAME": "Dashboard",
    "submenu": [
        {
            "ID": 1052,
            "MODULE_ID": 444,
            "MODULENAME": "Map Monitoring",
        },
        {
            "ID": 1053,
            "MODULE_ID": 444,
            "MODULENAME": "Map Status Terminal",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ID": 445,
    "MODULE_ID": 1112,
    "MODULENAME": "Dummy",
    "submenu": [
        {
            "ID": 1055,
            "MODULE_ID": 445,
            "MODULENAME": "Dolor",
        },
        {
            "ID": 1056,
            "MODULE_ID": 445,
            "MODULENAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
        }
    ]
}
```

The Nested array on `submenu` relation array is searchable. **The problem** is, i want both the parent and child array *searchable*.
if I set `"search": "lorem"` body in postman, the result should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 445,
        "MODULE_ID": 1112,
        "MODULENAME": "Dummy",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "ID": 1056,
                "MODULE_ID": 445,
                "MODULENAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Or if `"search": "Dummy"`, all data `Dummy` will show, like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 445,
        "MODULE_ID": 1112,
        "MODULENAME": "Dummy",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "ID": 1055,
                "MODULE_ID": 445,
                "MODULENAME": "Dolor",
            },
            {
                "ID": 1056,
                "MODULE_ID": 445,
                "MODULENAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I try to convert to Laravel Collection on my Controller, but it's doesn't work. **The result is same**:

```
$search = $request->search;

if(isset($search)) {
    $data = collect($query)->filter(function($item) use ($search) {
        return Str::startsWith($item->MODULENAME, $search);
    });
}
```

**My Query**

```
$query = NavModule::where('VALIDSTATUS', 1)
    ->with(['submenu' => function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('VALIDSTATUS', 1);
        $q->select('ID', 'MODULE_ID', 'MODULENAME');
    }])
    ->where('MODULETYPE', 'MAIN')
    ->where('LEVELNUMBER', 1)
    ->where('VALIDSTATUS', 1)
    ->select('ID', 'MODULE_ID', 'MODULENAME')
    ->orderBy('ORDERNUMBER', 'ASC')
    ->get();

$search = $request->search;

if(isset($search)) {
    $data = collect($query)->filter(function($item) use ($search) {
        return Str::startsWith($item->MODULENAME, $search);
    });
}

$data = $query;
```

** UPDATE **

I try @mrhn option, but it's not result that I want.

```
NavModule::whereHas('submenu', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('MODULENAME', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
})->with('submenu')
```

*result*

```
[
    {
        "ID": 445,
        "MODULE_ID": 1112,
        "MODULENAME": "Dummy",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "ID": 1055,
                "MODULE_ID": 445,
                "MODULENAME": "Dolor",
            },
            {
                "ID": 1056,
                "MODULE_ID": 445,
                "MODULENAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It's return the One main array only, but return all the nested array data. I just want to return only 1 match data.
I add `->with('submenu')` because Laravel not return relation array if not add it.

I'll appreciate every answer and option from this forum. Thank you

**update 22 july 2022**

- still haven't found the answer

Comment: Using laravel collection methods for what can be a SQL operation is not optimal, can you include your query to see if we can change that to work like you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all answer and comment. I have solve this problem. Here my code:

**Controller**

```
////////////////////
NavModule::where(fn ($query) =>
                $query->where('MODULENAME', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->where('VALIDSTATUS', '1')
                ->orderBy('ORDERNUMBER', 'ASC')
                    ->orWhereHas(
                        'submenu', fn ($subquery) =>
                            $subquery
        ->where('MODULENAME', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
     )                
   )   
  ->with('submenu')
  ->where('MODULETYPE', 'MAIN')
  ->where('LEVELNUMBER', 1)
  ->where('VALIDSTATUS', 1)
  ->select('ID', 'MODULE_ID', 'MODULENAME')
  ->orderBy('ORDERNUMBER', 'ASC')
  ->get();
//////////////// Rest of code
```

**Model**

```
public function submenu()
    {
        $search = request('search') ? : ""; 

        return $this->hasMany(NavModuleSub::class, 'MODULE_ID','ID')->where('MODULENAME', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you can just use `whereHas()` to achieve what you want. This function can query relationships, remember to add your current queries to my example.

```
NavModule::whereHas('submenu', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('MODULENAME', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
})
```

Comment: I have try this, but it's not solution that i want. It's return all the nested array, not only 1 object.

Comment: You will get all the nested array, it filters the navmodules.

Comment: Think your wording of the comment, is conflicting what nested array is. Do you want the Navmodules filtered or the submenus? or both for that matter.

Comment: I want filter the submenus. I try your option, but its still return all submenu data. Not 1 matched data only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use where condition on relation methods, you can use like  bellow code

in your Menu model

```php
public function subMenus():HasMany

{
 
  return $this->hasMany(SubMenu::class)->where('condition_key','condition_value')

}

//using 

Menus::with('subMenus')->get();
```

or you can more where method

```
Menus::with(['subMenus'=>fn($q)=>$q->where('condition_field','condition_value')
->where('fo','bar'))->get();
```

you can create more methods according to status for example

```php
public function subMenusWithfoo():HasMany

{
 
  return $this->hasMany(SubMenu::class)
    ->where('condition_key','condition_value')
    ->where('bar','foo');

}

//using

Menu::with('subMenusWithfoo')->get();
```